# Display the text value of an index from ViewData list of items in MVC, Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewdata

I'll try to keep this short. I am new to MVC.

I have a Controller which creates a list of timeslots (like a schedule), and puts this into a ViewData.  I understand how to do this.

I know how to display this data in a drop down menu using `@Html.DropDownList`, for example my create page has the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TimeSlot", ViewData["TimeSlotsList"] as List<SelectListItem>)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TimeSlot)
```

My problem is on my index view, it displays the `modelItem => item.TimeSlot` and shows the value of the Time slot, (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeSlot)
```

I want to display the TEXT value of the index from the `ViewData[TimeSlotsList]` list.  Obviously the index will be the value of the `modelItem => item.TimeSlot`.

I know this would have been much easier if the TimeSlots was its own table in the database but it was not setup this way and at this point in time I can't change without causing myself all kinds of migration headaches, etc.

If anyone knows how to do this or can point me in the right direction it is hugely appreciated!  I tried some different ideas but nothing has worked yet.....

EDIT:

I Create the list of timeslots in my controller with this function:

```
private List<SelectListItem> CreateTimeSlotsList()
        {
            //Build Time Slot Drop Down
            List<SelectListItem> li1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10-10:50am, Tues Mar. 17", Value = "1" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "11-11:50am, Tues Mar. 17", Value = "2" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1:10-2pm, Tues Mar. 17", Value = "3" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2:10-3pm, Tues Mar. 17", Value = "4" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "3:30-4:20pm, Tues Mar. 17", Value = "5" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "8:30-9:20am, Wed Mar. 18", Value = "6" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "9:30-10:20am, Wed Mar. 18", Value = "7" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "11-11:50am, Wed Mar. 18", Value = "8" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1:10-2pm, Wed Mar. 18", Value = "9" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2:10-3pm, Wed Mar. 18", Value = "10" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Hands On/Demo", Value = "99" });
            ViewData["timeSlots"] = li1;
            return (li1);
        }
```

Then i use

```
ViewData["TimeSlotsList"] = CreateTimeSlots();
```

I want to display the TEXT value of the index of the above list.

Comment: When you say "text value of the index" do you mean the text that corresponds to the time slot's ID in the database, or do you mean "One, Two, Three, Four"?

Comment: How did you construct the contents of `ViewData["TimeSlotsList"]`?  From what data?

Comment: How are you generating the options for `TimeSlots` if you don't have a table for `TimeSlots`?

Comment: I made a simple function on my controller that creates the list, then I call that function with ViewData["TimeSlotsList"] = CreateTimeSlots();  See my edit above in my post

Comment: @user3431175 Okay, but what data did you build it from? Do you have a master list of time slot IDs and their descriptions?  Or is it all done by convention?  (i.e. 1 always means "6am-12pm" and everybody knows this.)

Comment: The list is not part of the database.  I wish I had planned it that way because then I would know exactly what to do.  Unfortunately I dont know how to do this with a ViewData list, and I cant change my database schema without other headaches.

Comment: Ann L. you are correct.  If the modelItem => item.TimeSlot value is 1, I want it to display the TEXT of index value 1 on the ViewData list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but:

- If you don't have access to the text descriptions of the time slots that you used to create the `TimeSlotList`;
- If you do still have the `TimeSlotList` in `ViewData` on the Index page;

... then you could try something like this:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => 
     ((List<SelectListItem>) ViewData["TimeSlotsList"])
     .Single(sli => sli.Value==modelItem.TimeSlot)
     .Text)
```

ETA:  But you know what I'd do?  I'd create a model for a `TimeSlot` object, populate a master list of them the way you're doing in your `CreateTimeSlots` function, and return that from your data layer the way you would the model objects you're getting.  Basically, simulate a master `TimeSlot` table.

Then I'd use that to

1. Build your `TimeSlotsList`, and
2. Build a `ViewModel` based on your model object that includes a `TimeSlot` object from your master list.

Then, you could do something like:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeSlot.TimeSlotDescription)
```

... on your Index page.

Comment: I am really close.  Using what you said I did this:

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TimeSlotsList"]).Single(sli => sli.Value == "3").Text)

Comment: Okay figured it out using the list (i dont want to do a viewmodel because the current view has lots of customizations I dont want to rebuild the entire view).  This command worked:  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TimeSlotsList"]).Single(sli => Convert.ToInt32(sli.Value) == item.TimeSlot).Text)